# Search SQL by partial number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT e.id AS e_id, e.min_amount AS e_min_amount FROM pair e
```

For table column `e.min_amount` I have numbers like 14500. I would like to search by value 5 and get the row with partial match. I tried this:

```
SELECT e.id AS e_id, e.min_amount AS e_min_amount FROM pair e where cast(e.min_amount_per_distribution as text) like CONCAT('%','%s','%')
```

Using Java code:

```
searchParams.add(String.format(" cast(e.min_amount_per_distribution as text) like CONCAT('%','%s','%')", minAmountDistParam));
```

I get error during execution.

Do you know how I can implement properly this?

Answer (score 0):

i tested this under a Fiddle and found that your query, in concept, is working, take a look:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s1G9TTXsPK71cwVhkuS1j7/0

I modified the `CONCAT` to use a plain string like this `'%9%'`

The only problem I see is that the query you show as example have the following:

```sql
SELECT e.id AS e_id, e.min_amount AS e_min_amount FROM pair e where cast(e.min_amount_per_distribution as text) like CONCAT('%','%s','%')
```

And it should be this:

```sql
SELECT e.id AS e_id, e.min_amount AS e_min_amount FROM pair e where cast(e.e_min_amount as text) like CONCAT('%','%s','%')
```

The alias for the `min_amount` column is not `min_amount_per_distribution` but `e_min_amount`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I found one issue: I have into the table row value `0.0008`. When I send a search value `8000` I get a search result which his not correct. Any idea how I can fix it?